# Why realloc deadlock after clone syscall?

Tags: c, clone, deadlock, realloc

I have a problem that realloc() deadlocks sometime after clone() syscall.

My code is:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#define CHILD_STACK_SIZE 4096*4
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)
#define log(str) fprintf(stderr, "[pid:%d tid:%d] "str, getpid(),gettid())

int clone_func(void *arg){
    int *ptr=(int*)malloc(10);
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<200000; i++)
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(int)*i);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int flags = 0;
    flags = CLONE_VM;
    log("Program started.\n");
    int *ptr=NULL;
    ptr = malloc(16);
    void *child_stack_start = malloc(CHILD_STACK_SIZE);
    int ret = clone(clone_func, child_stack_start +CHILD_STACK_SIZE, flags, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<200000; i++)
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(int)*i);

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the callstack in gdb is:

```
[pid:13268 tid:13268] Program started.
^Z[New LWP 13269]

Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
#1  0x0000000000408630 in _L_lock_11249 ()
#2  0x000000000040797f in realloc ()
#3  0x0000000000400515 in main () at test-realloc.c:36
(gdb) i thr
  2 LWP 13269  0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
* 1 LWP 13268  0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
(gdb) thr 2
[Switching to thread 2 (LWP 13269)]#0  0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040ba0e in __lll_lock_wait_private ()
#1  0x0000000000408630 in _L_lock_11249 ()
#2  0x000000000040797f in realloc ()
#3  0x0000000000400413 in clone_func (arg=0x7fffffffe53c) at test-realloc.c:20
#4  0x000000000040b889 in clone ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My OS is debian linux-2.6.32-5-amd64, with GNU C Library (Debian EGLIBC 2.11.3-4) stable release version 2.11.3. I deeply suspect that eglibc is the criminal on this bug. 
On clone() syscall, is it not enough before using realloc()?

Comment: Are you sure `CLONE_VM` is what you want?

Comment: To Michael Foukarakis, yes, I wanna create a new thread, not process. And I find the reason of this problem. see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `clone` with `CLONE_VM` yourself -- or if you do, you have to at least make sure you restrict yourself from invoking any function from the standard library after calling `clone` in either the parent or the child. In order for multiple threads or processes to share the same memory, the implementations of any functions which access shared resources (like the heap) need to

1. be aware of the fact that multiple flows of control are potentially accessing it so they can arrange to perform the appropriate synchronization, and
2. be able to obtain information about their own identities via the thread pointer, usually stored in a special machine register. This is completely implementation-internal, and thus you cannot arrange for a new "thread" which you create yourself via `clone` to have a properly setup thread pointer.

The proper solution is to use `pthread_create`, not `clone`.

Comment: Thank you. You mean standard library is not thread-safe? Or is not clone-safe?

Comment: The only way it can be thread-safe is to be *aware* of its threads, and for threads to be aware of their own existence. Neither of these is possible if you bypass it. `pthread_create` is the correct way to use `clone` with `CLONE_VM`. Aside from facilitating automatic stack allocation if you don't provide your own, the main thing `pthread_create` does is managing the internal bookkeeping needed for synchronized access to shared resources to work right.

Comment: And yes, I think the phrase you used, "not clone-safe", is a very good way to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this:

```
for (i=0; i<200000; i++)
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(int)*i);
free(ptr);
```

The first time through the loop, `i` is zero.  `realloc( ptr, 0 )` is equivalent to `free( ptr )`, and you cannot `free` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your memtion. I modify the code with non-zero i. And the realloc() deadlock is still there.

Comment: I don't think this is OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I add a flag, CLONE_SETTLS, in clone() syscall. Then the deadlock is gone.
So I think eglibc's realloc() used some TLS data. When new thread create without a new TLS, some locks (in TLS) shared between this thread and his father, and realloc() using those locks stucked. So, if somebody want to use clone() directly, the best way is alloc a new TLS to new thread.

code snippet likes this:

```
flags = CLONE_VM | CLONE_SETTLS;
struct user_desc* p_tls_desc = malloc(sizeof(struct user_desc));
clone(clone_func, child_stack_start +CHILD_STACK_SIZE, flags, NULL, NULL, p_tls_desc, NULL);
```

Comment: Passing a pointer to an uninitialized `struct user_desc` is definitely not providing a valid TLS block for the new thread. You're lucky (or unlucky) this isn't crashing. If it works, it's by virtue of undefined behavior happening to make "the right thing" happen; this is not a stable/reproducible result.

Comment: Also, unless you're on 32-bit x86, `user_desc` is not even used. Instead, the pointer is treated as a direct pointer to the TLS base. This might be why it's not crashing quite so horribly, but it's still not doing the right thing. From your question, it looks like you're using x86_64.